# Android Junit Test Cases

Tags: android, testing

How can I stop the android Junit test application in the mid.I want to stop the execution of my application in particular place.Is it possible?Please give your suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

Set the breakpoint in desired place in IDE and run test project in debug mode.

Note that debug execution is a bit slower than  run mode.

hope this answer satisfies your question

Answer (score -1):

click on the **stop** button in the junit column. But again if you return, the testcases will be running from the beginning.